# Insert to database from multiple inputs Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

The response from the request is forbidden. I really don't know why.

I am trying to just insert into the database data from multiple inputs. The single inputs are stored correctly. The request has not any rules, so it is impossible that the error comes from there.

Let me show you my code:

```
 public function store(CreateRequest $request)
 {  
      $l = new l();
      $l->user_id = $request->input('registered');
      $l->description = $request->input('descri');
      $l->save();
      $lastInsertedId= $l->id;              
      $input = $request->all();
      $condition = $input['nym'];
      foreach ($condition as $key => $condition) {
         $le = new le();    
         $le->lid = $lastInsertedId;
         $le->deman = $input['nym'][$key];
         $le->dni = $input['dni'][$key];
         $le->address = $input['address'][$key];
         $le->contact_number = $input['contactnum'][$key];
         $le->def = $input['abo'][$key];
         $le->defe = $input['pro'][$key];
         $le->created_at = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
         $le->save();
     }
     return redirect('blog')->with('ok', trans('back/blog.stored'));
}
```

The info for the multiple inputs is coming from here:

```
<tbody class="input_fields_wrap">      
    <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="nym[]" value="que" readonly="" style="outline:none;border:none;border-width:0px;"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="dni[]" value="funci" readonly="" style="outline:none;border:none;border-width:0px;"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="address[]" value="one" readonly="" style="outline:none;border:none;border-width:0px;"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="contactnum[]" value="13" readonly="" style="outline:none;border:none;border-width:0px;"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="abo[]" value="nem" readonly="" style="outline:none;border:none;border-width:0px;"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="pro[]" value="por" readonly=""</td>
       <td><a class="remove_field">Eliminar</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: here,why are you using a value ? `<td><input type="text" name="nym[]" value="que" readonly="" style="outline:none;border:none;border-width:0px;"></td>`? and read only if you want to take input

Comment: Has something to do with jquery and view styling.

Comment: its pure html thing. just tell me, If you want to get user input, why you keep those fields readonly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

I modified the model adding fillable propeties:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```